# dojo make a widget react to a published event

Tags: dojo

Im trying to figure out how to close a pop up dialog based on a published event .. i.e when a person moves the mouse to another part of the page.(i only want it closed when i move to this part of the page) Is this possible

i have a topic published when the user moves off this area.

```
 _hoverOffArea : function() {
    topic.publish("messageRollOver/close");
   },
```

how do i get my popup to subscribe to this topic and close itself ?

```
          var tooltip = new TooltipDialog({
             onMouseLeave : function() {  

                     },
             onBlur : function() {
             }
          });       

          messageTooltip.set("content", rollOver.domNode);

              popup.open({
                popup: tooltip,
                around: e
              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be over thinking it.  The `dojo/topic` module has a `subscribe` method which takes a topic name ("messageRollOver/close") and a function to fire when the message is published.

```
topic.subscribe('messageRollOver/close',function(args){
  console.log('close tooltip');
});
```

You can pass arbitrary parameters to the publish message that are then passed to the subscribe:

```
topic.subscribe("messageRollOver/close",function(arg1){
  console.log("arg1 = ",arg1);
});
var tooltip = new TooltipDialog(/*params*/);
topic.publish("messageRollOver/close",tooltip);
```

when the subscribe function is invoked, arg1 would be the second argument to the topic#publish function call.

Comment: i know i can subscribe to the topic but how do i get the tooltip to subscribe to the topic?... maybe im missing something obvious but i cnt figure it out...

Comment: I updated my answer with information on how to pass around parameters.